# Finding percentages with this query

Tags: sql, percentage

The question is:
Query 4. Write a query to list out the product names and the percentage of customers that have
ordered the product. Format the percentage with the percentage symbol.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT productName, CONCAT(ROUND(Products.productCode/(SELECT SUM(customerNumber) FROM Customers)*100, 2), '%') AS CustomerPercentage FROM Customers
JOIN Orders ON Orders.customerNumber = Customers.customerNumber
JOIN OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.orderNumber = Orders.orderNumber
JOIN Products ON Products.productCode = OrderDetails.productCode
GROUP BY Products.productCode;
```

When I do this I keep getting 0% for all values. What should I do to prevent this error from continuously occurring?

Comment: Dividing a product code by a count just seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are using *integer* division.

You need to use a decimal value in your calculation (which has higher order of precendence) to force an implicit cast to decimal.

Try

```
CONCAT(ROUND(Products.productCode/(SELECT SUM(customerNumber) FROM Customers)*100.0, 2), '%')
```